# Regular expression find and replace to wrap tags

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Does anyone know how to use regex to find and replace certain word with

```
<b>[Keyword]</b>
```

I tried to use [`Regex.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) but it seems it only support direct replacement instead of appending `<b></b>` at begin and last of the keyword.

Example:

```
Hello World!
```

Keyword:

```
Hello
```

Output:

```
<b>Hello</b> World!
```

Comment: Could you put the code snippet you used to do the `Regex.Replace()`?

Comment: read about capture group! You have to find "(keyword1|keyword2|keyword3)" and in replace string you have to reference capture group (it is "<b>\\1</b>" or "<b>$1</b>").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string
            input = "Hello World!",
            keyword = "Hello";

        var result = Regex
            .Replace(input, keyword, m => 
                String.Format("<b>{0}</b>", m.Value));
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ninja skills with Regular and Lambda expressions. Helped my out, thanks dude!

Comment: @MoeHoward In this case, using lambda expression is "an overkill". There is a built-in `$&` backreference that can be used in the plain text replacement pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any lambda to re-use the whole match value inside a replacement pattern, you may refer to the whole match value using the `$&` backreference. See [*Substitutions in Regular Expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions):

> `$&`    Includes a copy of the entire match in the replacement string. For more information, see [Substituting the Entire Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#EntireMatch).

C# code:

```
var input = "Hello World!";
var keyword = "Hello";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, Regex.Escape(keyword), "<b>$&</b>");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

See the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/iq0qN0).

However, this code above makes little sense as you can achieve the same with a mere string `.Replace`: `var result = input.Replace(keyword, $"<b>{keyword}</b>")`. Hence, here are some ideas where you want to use the regex:

**Whole word matching**

- *Regular word boundaries* (if `keyword` consists of letters/digits/underscores ("word" chars) only): `Regex.Replace(input, $@"\b{keyword}\b", "<b>$&</b>")`
- *Unambiguous word boundaries* (if `keyword` may contain non-word chars): `Regex.Replace(input, $@"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(keyword)}(?!\w)", "<b>$&</b>")`
- *Whitespace word boundaries* (a whole word is a chunk of non-whitespace chars wrapped with whitespaces or start/end of string): `Regex.Replace(input, $@"(?<!\S){Regex.Escape(keyword)}(?!\S)", "<b>$&</b>")`

**Case insensitive matching**

You may need a regex like this to ensure the same case of the keyword in the replaced string when performing a case insensitive regex search:

```
Regex.Replace(input, Regex.Escape(keyword), "<b>$&</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

See [another C# demo](https://ideone.com/NQywVW):

```
var keyword = "A+";
Console.WriteLine("Unambiguous WB: " + Regex.Replace("A+B and A++", $@"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(keyword)}(?!\w)", "<b>$&</b>"));
// => Unambiguous WB: A+B and <b>A+</b>+
keyword = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine("Regular WB: " + Regex.Replace("Hello World! Hello,World!", $@"\b{keyword}\b", "<b>$&</b>"));
// => Regular WB: <b>Hello</b> World! <b>Hello</b>,World!
Console.WriteLine("Whitespace WB: " + Regex.Replace("Hello, Hello Hello!", $@"(?<!\S){Regex.Escape(keyword)}(?!\S)", "<b>$&</b>"));
// => Whitespace WB: Hello, <b>Hello</b> Hello!
keyword = "hello";
Console.WriteLine("Case innsensitive: " + Regex.Replace("Hello, hello World!", Regex.Escape(keyword), "<b>$&</b>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
// => Case innsensitive: <b>Hello</b>, <b>hello</b> World!
```