# Find & replace text while maintaining the text CaSe of match

Tags: c#, regex

I have simple functionality on a website where the user enters the keyword to be searched and matched keywords are wrapped with `<span></span>` and the color is also changed for the matched keywords.

The code below finds & replaces the keywords in Title where a match is found but changing the case of the match is changed based on how keywords were entered.

```
protected String getTitle(object title)
{
    string sTitle = title.ToString();

    Regex regex = null;
    string pattern = @"(\b(?:" + _Keyword.ToString().Trim() + @")\b)(?![^<]*?>)";
    regex = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    sTitle = regex.Replace(sTitle, "<span class='keyword-highlight'>" + _Keyword + "</span>");
    return sTitle;
}
```

Actual Text = `Trump asked Australia to help investigate Mueller`
Searck Keyword = `australia`

Let us say I entered the keyword in lower case `australia` in this case it will find the match and replace it `Australia` with `australia` which grammatically is wrong as I want to main the text case as it is in the actual sentence.

Result = `Trump asked australia to help investigate Mueller`

How can I make this change in the above code, if I remove `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` then it will not match as now search keyword is CaSe SenSiTive

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55040912/3832970). You need no capturing group since you want to wrap the *whole match* with a pair of tags since there exists `&$` backreference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$1` (the first captured group)

[Substituting a Numbered Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141069/what-is-1-and-2-in-regular-expressions)

> The `$number` language element includes the last substring matched by
>   the number capturing group in the replacement string, where number is
>   the index of the capturing group.

**Example**

```
var input = "Trump asked Australia to help investigate Mueller";
var keyword = "australia"; 

var pattern = @"(\b(?:" + keyword.Trim() + @")\b)(?![^<]*?>)";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "<span class='keyword-highlight'>$1</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
Trump asked <span class='keyword-highlight'>Australia</span> to help investigate Mueller
```

Comment: Oh that was simple, i learnt something new..