# Add a string to a match found with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

```
string input = "bla bla 4 bla bla 8";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\d-]", "<strong></strong>");
```

my outupt should be

```
bla bla <strong>4</strong> bla bla <strong>8</strong>
```

is it possible to get it with a simple regex replace?

Comment: Just replace `"<strong></strong>"` with  `"<strong>$&</strong>"` - no need of any additional groups or `$1`

Answer (score 1):

As the replacement, use `<strong>$&</strong>` instead. Then you need to capture the numbers, so the regex pattern might look like: `\d+`

The `$&` in the replacement puts the entire match into the replacement string.

All together, it looks like:

```
string input = "bla bla 4 bla bla 8";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+", "<strong>$&</strong>");
```

EDIT: Made my explanation match the sample code, thanks @pwilcox; also took @Wiktor Stribiżew's advice and removed the unecessary capture group used for the replacement and replaced it with `$&` to sub in the entire match, a trick I was embarrassingly unaware of

Comment: Voted you up.  But just so you know your `(\d+)` in the narrative portion is different than your `([\d-]+)` in the code block.  Both do the job, but the former is simpler.

Comment: Adding a redundant group is "an overkill". Use `$&` as is shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55040912/3832970).

Comment: Thank you both for the corrections/suggestions, I've updated my answer to match